# xCode sqlite query

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

This must be a stupid problem but i cant get my query to work. Its as if my database is empty (I double checked, its not). Its a simple `SELECT * FROM table` query. This is how i try it:

```
+(MyDatabase *)database{
    if (database == nil) {
        database = [[MyDatabase alloc] init];
    }
    return database;
}
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSString *sqliteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"personsDB" ofType:@"sqlite3"];
        if (sqlite3_open([sqliteDb UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Fail to open Database.");
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

and

```
-(NSArray *)getAllRows{
    NSMutableArray *retArray =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM persons";

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSLog(@"checking SQLITE_OK?");
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"SQLITE_OK");
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            int personID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            char *personChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            int gender = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);
            int related = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 3);

            NSString *person = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:personChars];
            MyDBInfo *info = [[MyDBInfo alloc] initWithpersonID:personID person:person gender:gender related:related ];

            [retArray addObject:info];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    return retArray;
}
```

I think this is all the interesting stuff.

In my Log I get `checking SQLITE_OK?`, but no `SQLITE_OK`. I'm not getting `Fail to open Database.` so I'm assuming that its all good there.

My Database is full and there is a table called `persons`. I'm very new to `sqlite` in `iOS apps`.

Thank you.

Comment: yes, in the `personsDB`.

Comment: Are you sure the db is included in your bundle? I sometimes have added files to my xcode project and they're not automatically included. Select the target in the top of the project navigator, click on the target, select the target in the main panel, select "Build Phases", and see if your db is included in the "Copy Bundle Resources".

Comment: Needless to say, I believe your code is fine (other than `sqlite3_open` creating the db and `sqlite3_prepare_v2` not looking at it's error message). It's got to be the absence of the db, which will be discovered if you `sqlite3_open_v2([sqliteDb UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);` or if you look at the `sqlite3_errmsg(database)` when your `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails (it will probably say "table not found").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Are you sure the db is included in your bundle? The default behavior of [`sqlite3_open`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) is `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`, so it will be created on your device/simulator if it wasn't there already, so you won't see `Fail to open Database`. Use `sqlite3_open_v2` if you don't want `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`. Anyway, I sometimes have added files to my xcode project and they're not automatically included in my bundle. Select the target in the top of the project navigator, click on the target, select the target in the main panel, select "Build Phases", and see if your db is included in the "Copy Bundle Resources".
2. Probably unrelated, but I always copy the database from the bundle to documents folder (if it's not there already).
3. If I don't receive the expected SQLITE_OK, I always look at my return code or log my error message and error codes (and this would probably report that the table in question was not found, which would have let you identify the problem).

Thus,

```
NSLog(@"%s db err '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB), sqlite3_errcode(contactDB));
```

Comment: Thank you, I was going crazy :P